# How to write update query in Mongoose or MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schema

```
var myschema = new schema({
            username: { type: String, required: validationMessages.required, index: { unique: true }, lowercase: true },               
            siteConfig:{ type: Array}
        });
```

And my document will be look like this

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5411a6fb4bcc787927825dac"),
"username" : "admin" 
    "siteConfig" : [ 
    {
        "name" : "landing"
        "page" : {
            "name" : "home",                               
            "sections" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "header",
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "bodycontent",
                },

                {
                    "name" : "footer",
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

}

I want to update the property **“name”:”header”** under **siteConfig->page->sections** WHERE the criteria is match the following

**(“username”:”admin”  &&  “siteConfig.name”: “landing  “&&  “page.name”:”home”)**

I have trired with dot notation and elematch but I don't know the right way to write update query.

Comment: You need to read the documentation on the [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator for this. And what that is basically going to tell you is that only the **fisrt** and "outer" array element is going to match, regardless of your query conditions. So if you intend to "update" members of an embedded array embedded in another array, then you need to re-think your structure. This will not work unless you always "know" the position of the inner array when issuing the update.

Comment: Right, I can able to update by following query (db.schema.update({username:"admin",siteConfig:{$elemMatch:{name:"landing"}}},{$set:{"siteConfig.0.page.sections.$.name":"demo"}})) but I need to check one more condition is if "Section.$.name"="header" then update the 'section.$.name':"demo"

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem might be that you haven't defined the schema of `siteConfig`. First, update your schema like this:

```
var ObjSchema = new Schema({
    ...
    siteConfig: [
        {
            name: {type: String},
            page: {
                name: {type: String},
                sections: [
                    {
                        name: {type: String},
                    }
                ],
            },
        }
    ],
});
```

Now you can update like this:

```
var query = {
    username: 'admin',
    'siteConfig.name': 'landing',
    'siteConfig.page.name': 'home',
};
var update = {
    $set: {
        'siteConfig.page.sections.0.name': 'header',
    },
};
var options = {
    multi: true,
};

Obj.update(query, update, options, function(err, numAffected) {
    ...
});
```

I wasn't sure what you wanted to update so you can change the `update` dict how you want. Change the `options` dict if you don't want to update multiple documents.

Comment: Okay, I will add schema and check then let you know. and Is there any way to check one more condition like"siteConfig.page.sections.0.name="header" then I will update the this property?

Comment: Thanks and sorry for delay of response. you are right we have to define each properties of 'siteConfig' in schema as you defined above in order to find or update nested object and not sure I have tried the above (so I will try one more time and update you the status) but I remember that I have defined each property of siteConfig but not got expected things so moved to other solution like find() and modify manually then save().